# Getting a badge if the player's value is greater than that number(Roblox Studio)

Tags: lua, roblox

I'm trying to make it so that if the user has a `ValueKey` folder. and the name of the currency is `ValueKey`

```
local badges = game:GetService("BadgeService")
local badgeId  = 2130265816
local players = game:GetService("Players")

players.PlayerAdded:Connect(function(player)
    local value = players.ValueKey.ValueKey
    value.Value.Changed:Connect(function(newVal)
        if newVal == 100 then --award badge for 100 candies
            --badges:AwardBadge(player.UserId, badgeId)
            print('you received a badge')
        end
    end)
end)
```

But for some reason the text does not want to be displayed in the console, I can’t understand why at least the value has the number 100 or more

Comment: Try changing `players.ValueKey` to `player.ValueKey`.

Comment: I already did that but it still won't read.

Answer (score 0):

You're probably putting the `PValue` path wrong, which is why it isn't working!

Try this:

```lua
local badges = game:GetService("BadgeService")
local badgeId  = 2130265816
local players = game:GetService("Players")

players.PlayerAdded:Connect(function(player)
    local Pvalue = player.ValueKey.ValueKey
    --Make sure ur fetching the correct value with correct path in player.

    if Pvalue && Pvalue.value == 100 or Pvalue.value == "100" then
        --badges:AwardBadge(player.UserId, badgeId)
        print('you received a badge')
    end
    if Pvalue then
       Pvalue.value.Changed:Connect(function(newVal)
            if newVal == 100 or newValue == "100" then --award badge for 100 candies
                --badges:AwardBadge(player.UserId, badgeId)
                print('you received a badge')
            end
        end)
    end
end)
```

Don't forget to check the print in the server sided console!

Comment: `19:22:29.181  ValueKey is not a valid member of Folder "Players.TVOFFicial1.ValueKey"  -  Server - Badge:6` - outputs this cleanly and says that there is no such path

Comment: You're probably putting the wrong path! Start the game and show the screenshot of the ValueKey location or send me the path of it! Ex: Game/Players/TVOFFicial1/......

Comment: @KirillShishkov

Comment: i figured it out and solved the problem thanks